# Найти клиентов которые не покупали ничего SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
  id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
  CustomerName nvarchar(15) UNIQUE,
  Address nvarchar(20),
  City nvarchar(20),
  Country nvarchar(20)
)
CREATE TABLE Orders (
  id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
  CustomerId int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers (id),
  EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employees (id),
  OrderDate date,
  ShipersID int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (ShipersID) REFERENCES Shipers (id)
)

INSERT INTO Customers
  VALUES ('Begt', 'rht', 'Berlin', 'Germany'), ('Uuu', 'ththj', 'Kyiv', 'Ukraine')
INSERT INTO Orders
  VALUES (2, 1, '2017-11-4', 2), (1, 2, '2018-4-12', 1), (2, 3, '2018-3-24', 3)

SELECT
  Customers.CustomerName
FROM Customers
JOIN Orders
  ON Customers.id <> Orders.CustomerId
ORDER BY CustomerName
```

так не проходит выводит всех

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  c.CustomerName
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.id = o.CustomerId
WHERE o.CustomerId IS NULL
ORDER BY CustomerName
```

Вам нужен `LEFT JOIN` и проверка на отсутствие покупателя в таблице заказов (`Orders` ).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Или так

```
SELECT
  CustomerName
FROM Customers
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT CustomerId FROM Orders)
```

Но вариант с left join лучше.